# Class error message that I don't know how to solve

Tags: c++, class

I have an error problem... I've searched the internet but haven't found a real solution to the problem. Most people solve it by including the right header file but i've included all mine.

I get this error message: undefined reference to `ShapeLib::Circle::~Circle()'. I don't know what's wrong...

This is the code of main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <textwindow.h>
#include <circle.h>

using namespace ShapeLib;

void test(){
    TextWindow tw;

    Circle circle(5);

    tw.print(circle.getArea());
    tw.start();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    test();

    return 0;
}
```

circle.h code:

```
#pragma once
#include "math.h"
#include "point.h"
#include <QPainter>

namespace ShapeLib{

    /**
    * A class representing a circle with a position in a two-dimensional
    * plane.
    */
    class Circle{

    public:

        /**
        * Creates a new circle with the radius 0 positioned at origin.
        */
        Circle();

        /**
        * Creates a new circle with the given radius positioned at
        * (centerX, centerY).
        */
        Circle(const double radius, const double centerX=0, const double centerY=0);

        /**
        * Returns this circle's radius.
        *
        * @return This circle's radius.
        */
        double getRadius() const;

        /**
        * Returns this circle's circumference.
        *
        * @return This circle's circumference.
        */
        double getCircumference() const;

        /**
        * Sets this circle's circumference to newCircumference.
        *
        * @parameter newCircumference This circles's new circumference.
        */
        void setCircumference(const double newCircumference);

        /**
        * Returns this circle's area.
        *
        * @return This circle's area.
        */
        double getArea() const;

        /**
        * Sets this circle's area to newArea.
        *
        * @parameter newArea This circle's new area.
        */
        void setArea(const double newArea);

        /**
        * Checks if point is located inside this circle.
        *
        * @parameter point The point to check for.
        * @return True if the point is inside this circle, otherwise false.
        */
        bool contains(const Point *point) const;

        /**
        * Moves this circle by dx in the x-direction and dy in the y-direction.
        *
        * @parameter dx The amount to move in the x-direction.
        * @parameter dy The amount to move in the y-direction.
        */
        void move(const double dx, const double dy);

        /**
        * Returns the x-coordinate for this circle's left side.
        *
        * @return The x-coordinate for this circle's left side.
        */
        double getLeft() const;

        /**
        * Returns the x-coordinate for this circle's right side.
        *
        * @return The x-coordinate for this circle's right side.
        */
        double getRight() const;

        /**
        * Returns the y-coordinate for this circle's top side.
        *
        * @return The y-coordinate for this circle's top side.
        */
        double getTop() const;

        /**
        * Returns the y-coordinate for this circle's bottom side.
        *
        * @return The y-coordinate for this circle's bottom side.
        */
        double getBottom() const;

        /**
        * Draws this circle with the provided background color and painter.
        */
        void draw(QPainter *painter, const Qt::GlobalColor color) const;

        ~Circle();

    private:
        double radius;
        Point *center; // Allocated dynamically for demonstrating destructors.

    };

}
```

circle.cpp code

```
#include "circle.h"
#include "point.h"
#include "math.h"

using namespace ShapeLib;

Circle::Circle(){
    radius = 0;
    center = new Point(0, 0);
}

Circle::Circle(const double radius, const double centerX, const double centerY) : radius(radius) {
    center = new Point(centerX, centerY);
}

double Circle::getRadius() const {
    return radius;
}

double Circle::getCircumference() const {
    return 2*M_PI*radius;
}
void Circle::setCircumference(const double newCircumference) {
    radius = 2*M_PI*newCircumference;
}

double Circle::getArea() const {
    return M_PI*pow(radius, 2);
}
void Circle::setArea(const double newArea){
    radius = sqrt(newArea/M_PI);
}
```

Comment: Where do you implement the destructor?

Answer (score 1):

You declared a destructor

```
~Circle();
```

but never implemented it in your cpp file

```
Circle::~Circle()
{
    delete center;
}
```

Also beware the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). As written, the default generated copy semantics of your class are broken, and would cause a double-deletion if copied. Therefore either make the class uncopyable or implement a user defined copy constructor and copy-assigment operator

```
Circle(Circle const&) = delete;
Circle& operator=(Circle const&) = delete;
```